# creating loop on recurring key pair in string

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string

Hi i am struggling to figure out how to utilize the information obtained from my API call. I am getting the following response as a string.

```
{"locales":[{"code":"pt-pt","name":"Portuguese - Portugal","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt2dbcc92784492912","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-09-08T13:11:26.343Z","updated_at":"2022-09-08T13:11:26.343Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"zh-tw","name":"Chinese - Taiwan","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt3598d563478e2c7f","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:36:12.349Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:36:12.349Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"zh-cn","name":"Chinese - China","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt5cde91e1b8f39ace","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:55.210Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:55.210Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"tr-tr","name":"Turkish - Turkey","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt726c15b4b78a72f1","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:44.723Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:44.723Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"th-th","name":"Thai - Thailand","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltf9fda6d4c82117f4","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:34.793Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:34.793Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"sv-se","name":"Swedish - Sweden","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt2ed0ec8012ccf98a","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:23.640Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:23.640Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"sl-si","name":"Slovenian - Slovenia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt543ba5583cf2458f","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:15.238Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:15.238Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"sk-sk","name":"Slovak - Slovakia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltc98d829b1ceb6de7","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:34:52.503Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:34:52.503Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"name":"Russian - Russia","fallback_locale":"en-us","code":"ru-ru","uid":"blt70cd5e083452b35c","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:34:41.204Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:34:41.204Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"ro-ro","name":"Romanian - Romania","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt365675e5bcb19e1a","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:55.747Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:55.747Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"pt-br","name":"Portuguese - Brazil","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt9012e544e7f2126b","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:42.431Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:42.431Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"pl-pl","name":"Polish - Poland","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt9e428a82856ee006","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:31.860Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:31.860Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"nl-be","name":"Nedeerlands - Belgie","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltec212fab6a6c6f74","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:08.745Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:08.745Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"nb-no","name":"Norwegian (Bokmal) - Norway","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltdb96160bb0b8be22","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:32:25.956Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:32:25.956Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"mt-mt","name":"Maltese - Malta","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt8e22ca471b1acf60","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:32:07.343Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:32:07.343Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"lv-lv","name":"Latvian - Latvia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltfcd2d156d7afbe94","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:33.605Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:33.605Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"lt-lt","name":"Lithuanian - Lithuania","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltefc7ef05e15fb675","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:22.811Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:22.811Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"ko-kr","name":"Korean - Korea","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt4a66819e3f9cad46","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:10.161Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:10.161Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"ja-jp","name":"Japanese - Japan","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt8c8f5288531efd99","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:32.993Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:32.993Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"it-it","name":"Italian - Italy","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt8937a904630e4764","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:19.718Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:19.718Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"id-id","name":"Indonesian - Indonesia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt52ed6bd483b0e8c7","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:02.396Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:02.396Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"hu-hu","name":"Hungarian - Hungary","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltcef0b2d39a7bea56","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:51.762Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:51.762Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"hr-hr","name":"Croatian - Croatia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt423a917bcdfcd458","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:37.231Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:37.231Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"he-il","name":"Hebrew - Israel","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt569ab41902eb340c","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:19.453Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:19.453Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"fr-fr","name":"French - France","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltcdcb320a632f4406","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:32.914Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:32.914Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"et-ee","name":"Estonian - Estonia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt0ab702938b5187e4","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:14.186Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:14.186Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"fi-fi","fallback_locale":"en-us","name":"Suomi - Suomi","uid":"bltaf4f59f8725eb7f1","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:05.874Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:05.874Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"es-es","name":"Espanol - Espana","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt2a15b0b710e98140","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:27:27.849Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:27:27.849Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"el-gr","name":"Greek - Greece","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltbb2f649a36fe0912","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:26:17.354Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:26:17.354Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"da-dk","name":"Dansk - Danmark","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt30113e17491ca0ce","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:25:45.607Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:25:45.607Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"cs-cz","name":"Catalan - Spain","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltf19ff838d595a9d3","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:25:09.789Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:25:09.789Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"ca-es","name":"Czech - Czechia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltee8373e62d922558","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:24:22.452Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:24:22.452Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"bg-bg","name":"Francais - Belgique","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt52c8ce375e72ef5a","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:22:49.897Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:22:49.897Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"ar-sa","name":"Arabic - Saudi Arabia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt66fa05a6ecc4dc79","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:20:52.005Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:20:52.005Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"de-de","name":"German - Germany","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blta8d4e6151eb54868","created_by":"blt04782762ff721824","updated_by":"blt04782762ff721824","created_at":"2022-07-18T18:02:08.318Z","updated_at":"2022-07-18T18:02:08.318Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"en-us","fallback_locale":null,"uid":"blt33fd33b513262543","created_by":"bltba80d10bf85baa29","updated_by":"bltba80d10bf85baa29","created_at":"2022-06-01T19:52:12.765Z","updated_at":"2022-06-01T19:52:12.765Z","name":"English - United States","ACL":[],"_version":1}]}
```

I am wanting to parse this string to effectively create a mapping of the vaules that follow after the "code" key

Ex

1: "pt-pt"

2: "zh-tw"

so on and so fourth...

This is all an effort to create an object that I can then run a foreach loop off of when updating json files on the server side of the application, each file will have a locale key replaced with this code and the file will be renamed with the code appended to the beginning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: nearly ten thousand characters for a question, that must be a record, right? [I think you should have taken the time to read the advice pages
from this site...](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let response = 
{"locales":[{"code":"pt-pt","name":"Portuguese - Portugal",
"fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt2dbcc92784492912",
"created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531",
"created_at":"2022-09-08T13:11:26.343Z","updated_at":"2022-09-08T13:11:26.343Z",
"ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"zh-tw","name":"Chinese - Taiwan",
"fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt3598d563478e2c7f",
"created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531",
"created_at":"2022-08-23T19:36:12.349Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:36:12.349Z",
"ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"zh-cn","name":"Chinese - China",
"fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt5cde91e1b8f39ace",
"created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531",
"created_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:55.210Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:55.210Z",
"ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"tr-tr","name":"Turkish - Turkey",
"fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt726c15b4b78a72f1",
"created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531",
"created_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:44.723Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:44.723Z",
"ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"th-th","name":"Thai - Thailand",
"fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltf9fda6d4c82117f4",
"created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531",
"created_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:34.793Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:34.793Z",
"ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"sv-se","name":"Swedish - Sweden",
"fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt2ed0ec8012ccf98a",
"created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:23.640Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:23.640Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"sl-si","name":"Slovenian - Slovenia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt543ba5583cf2458f","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:15.238Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:35:15.238Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"sk-sk","name":"Slovak - Slovakia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltc98d829b1ceb6de7","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:34:52.503Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:34:52.503Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"name":"Russian - Russia","fallback_locale":"en-us","code":"ru-ru","uid":"blt70cd5e083452b35c","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:34:41.204Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:34:41.204Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"ro-ro","name":"Romanian - Romania","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt365675e5bcb19e1a","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:55.747Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:55.747Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"pt-br","name":"Portuguese - Brazil","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt9012e544e7f2126b",
"created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:42.431Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:42.431Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"pl-pl","name":"Polish - Poland","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt9e428a82856ee006","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:31.860Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:31.860Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"nl-be","name":"Nedeerlands - Belgie","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltec212fab6a6c6f74","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:08.745Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:33:08.745Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"nb-no","name":"Norwegian (Bokmal) - Norway","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltdb96160bb0b8be22","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:32:25.956Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:32:25.956Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"mt-mt","name":"Maltese - Malta","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt8e22ca471b1acf60","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:32:07.343Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:32:07.343Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"lv-lv","name":"Latvian - Latvia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltfcd2d156d7afbe94","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:33.605Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:33.605Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"lt-lt","name":"Lithuanian - Lithuania",
"fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltefc7ef05e15fb675","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:22.811Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:22.811Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"ko-kr","name":"Korean - Korea","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt4a66819e3f9cad46","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:10.161Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:31:10.161Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"ja-jp","name":"Japanese - Japan","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt8c8f5288531efd99","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:32.993Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:32.993Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"it-it","name":"Italian - Italy","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt8937a904630e4764","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:19.718Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:19.718Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"id-id","name":"Indonesian - Indonesia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt52ed6bd483b0e8c7","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:02.396Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:30:02.396Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"hu-hu","name":"Hungarian - Hungary","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltcef0b2d39a7bea56","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:51.762Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:51.762Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},
{"code":"hr-hr","name":"Croatian - Croatia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt423a917bcdfcd458","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:37.231Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:37.231Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"he-il","name":"Hebrew - Israel","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt569ab41902eb340c","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:19.453Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:29:19.453Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"fr-fr","name":"French - France","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltcdcb320a632f4406","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:32.914Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:32.914Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"et-ee","name":"Estonian - Estonia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt0ab702938b5187e4","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:14.186Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:14.186Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"fi-fi","fallback_locale":"en-us","name":"Suomi - Suomi","uid":"bltaf4f59f8725eb7f1","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:05.874Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:28:05.874Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"es-es","name":"Espanol - Espana","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt2a15b0b710e98140","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:27:27.849Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:27:27.849Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"el-gr","name":"Greek - Greece","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltbb2f649a36fe0912","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:26:17.354Z",
"updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:26:17.354Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"da-dk","name":"Dansk - Danmark","fallback_locale":"en-us",
"uid":"blt30113e17491ca0ce","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:25:45.607Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:25:45.607Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"cs-cz","name":"Catalan - Spain","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltf19ff838d595a9d3","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:25:09.789Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:25:09.789Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"ca-es","name":"Czech - Czechia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"bltee8373e62d922558","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:24:22.452Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:24:22.452Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"bg-bg","name":"Francais - Belgique","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt52c8ce375e72ef5a","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:22:49.897Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:22:49.897Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"ar-sa","name":"Arabic - Saudi Arabia","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blt66fa05a6ecc4dc79","created_by":"blt1694396d92625531","updated_by":"blt1694396d92625531","created_at":"2022-08-23T19:20:52.005Z","updated_at":"2022-08-23T19:20:52.005Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"de-de","name":"German - Germany","fallback_locale":"en-us","uid":"blta8d4e6151eb54868","created_by":"blt04782762ff721824","updated_by":"blt04782762ff721824","created_at":"2022-07-18T18:02:08.318Z","updated_at":"2022-07-18T18:02:08.318Z","ACL":[],"_version":1},{"code":"en-us","fallback_locale":null,"uid":"blt33fd33b513262543","created_by":"bltba80d10bf85baa29","updated_by":"bltba80d10bf85baa29","created_at":"2022-06-01T19:52:12.765Z","updated_at":"2022-06-01T19:52:12.765Z","name":"English - United States","ACL":[],"_version":1}]}


console.log(response.locales[0].code)
console.log(response.locales[1].code)

for(i=0;i < response.locales.length;i++){
    console.log(response.locales[i].code)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, this worked like a charm! how would i handle this if the string is a variable? is throwing a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: can give example?